# Validation with javascript from list

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, list

I'm trying to validate a form filed via javascript. The idea is that the form filed has a set list of accepted values and only these values work. So if the field is black it will alert that the ID is incorrect. If the field has input which is not in the list it will display that ID is incorrect. I have gotten close. I just need a little more direction.

Here is my code:

```
script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm()
        {
            var x=document.forms["dispatch"]["ID1"].value;
            var arr=["CA238", "Pete", "John"];
            if x==(.inArray(inputVal, arr) > -1)
            {
  alert("Correct Dispatcher ID Required");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

<form id="form_242533" class="appnitro" name="dispatch" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
<li id="li_9" >
            <label class="description" for="element_1">Dispatch ID</label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_1" name="ID1" class="element text medium" type="text"  value=""/> Put your assigned dispatcher ID
        </div> 
        </li>

                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="Submit" value="Submit" />

                <input id="submit" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                <input type="reset" />

        </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
```

Comment: A "set list of accepted values", eh? How about a list box?

Comment: The idea behind the form filed is a user ID, Each user allowed to submit to the form will have a id in the list ( Currently in array ) they will put there ID in and it will validate letting the form submit, If they don't have a ID the form wont submit and tell them the id is missing or invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
if x==(.inArray(inputVal, arr) > -1)
```

to this:

```
if ($.inArray(x, arr) == -1)
```

if you're using jQuery.

---

If you don't have jQuery on the page, change it to this instead:

```
if (arr.indexOf(x) == -1)
```

Note however, that this method won't work in IE < 9. Use [the polyfill provided here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) to add `indexOf` support to older versions of IE.

Comment: changed it however still allows submission regardless of blank input or wrong input =/

Comment: @NathanDollinger - Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Its just javascript which im new to but any way i tried that and still received no results, could there be any other issues in the script or the form its self?

Comment: Okay i the first value in the list will work and the script till result false if its blank or not the first value but the other values in the list aren't working

Comment: I got it to work thanks for every ones help! The last problem was the spaces in the list

Comment: @NathanDollinger - I don't understand what you're saying. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/bUHWJ/

Comment: I got it to work updated your answer to reflect the working script Thank you sorry for the confusion some times i type to fast for my own good!